# Can someone Please tell me what's wrong in this query..?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
SELECT p.post_title FROM wp_posts p
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships tr on (p.ID = tr.object_id)
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt on (tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id)
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt2 on (tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt2.term_taxonomy_id)
WHERE 
tt2.term_id IN( 36, 32)
AND tt.term_id = 33
AND p.post_type = 'post'
```

Actually, i have two different taxonomy (namely status and category) each of those has many terms. there i have to check in one certain category term (that term_id 33) has how many posts whose statuses terms term_id 36 or 32.

Actually, i need to apply the condition to the same column ( of wp_term_taxonomy table) two times.

Above query return nothing.Guys, please help me out.

Comment: Check this blog btw: http://blog.jerryorr.com/2014/04/solve-your-problem-by-almost-asking.html

Comment: whoops, pressed reject edit when I ment approve.  my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use columns related to `LEFT JOIN TABLE` in `WHERE condition` otherwise these work as an `INNER JOIN` so

```
SELECT p.post_title FROM wp_posts p
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships tr on (p.ID = tr.object_id)
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt on (tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id) 
        AND tt.term_id = 33
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt2 on (tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt2.term_taxonomy_id) 
        AND tt2.term_id IN ( 36, 32)
  WHERE p.post_type = 'post'
```

Comment: Not working, it returning all records.

Comment: My suggestion is for SQL correct join usage  if you need a specific result ..  then explain better  your expected  result  .. could be that one or more than your left join must became inner join  .. you should add  a proper data sample ,your actual result and your expected  result  ..